I am trying to run SQL statement getting the syntax error
Error code returned:

Result: near "Type": syntax error
At line 2:

SQL statement:
SELECT
    InvoiceDate,
    BillingAddress,
    BillingCity,
    total,
    CASE
        WHEN total < 2.00 THEN 'Baseline Purchase'
        ELSE 'Top Performer'
    END AS Purchase Type
FROM
    Invoice
WHERE
    Purchase Type = 'Top Performer'
ORDER BY
    BillingCity


Just change your "AS" clause from AS Purchase Type -- to AS PurchaseType (no space).  Let your user interface have proper headings and labels.  Dont have your data columns have spaces in them.

What error do you get if you change Purchase Type to "Purchase Type" or PurchaseType in where and select?  Also what data type is "total" ?  are you comparing a "String" to a numeric field?  Why does it need to be < 2.00? and not just < 2?  Also you can't use Purchase Type in the where clause the alias is not available yet due to order of operation of a select statement unless SQLlite does something different...

Column names or aliases can't have spaces in them, as you have in Purchase Type. You can escape this name by using double quotes ("):
SELECT   InvoiceDate, BillingAddress, BillingCity, total, 
         CASE WHEN total < 2.00 THEN 'Baseline Purchase' 
              ELSE 'Top Performer' 
         END AS "Purchase Type"
         -- Here^-------------^ 
FROM     Invoice 
WHERE    "Purchase Type" = 'Top Performer'
ORDER BY BillingCity


I tried using the double quotes as well however the error is occurring at Line 1, when I am removing the CASE statement and only running the SELECT statement without IF and THEN its working fine

where clause is wrong too.  Purchase Type isn't available due to order of operation of a SQL statement.

You need to put your CASE WHEN in your WHERE statement. It does not recognise Purchase Type as it does not yet exist when you run the query.
SELECT   InvoiceDate, BillingAddress, BillingCity, total, 
     CASE WHEN total < 2.00 THEN 'Baseline Purchase' 
          ELSE 'Top Performer' 
     END AS "Purchase Type"
FROM     Invoice 
WHERE    total >= 2.00
ORDER BY BillingCity

